# Trying To Download & Save A PDF File Using Symfony2

Tags: php, curl, file-io, symfony

I am trying to download & save a PDF file from an online resource. I have seen the cookbook chapter on the File Uploads and tried to modify the technique for my own use. I just can't get this to work.

Controller Code:

```
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

use Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Shipment;

class WelcomeController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        echo $barcodeUrl  = "http://www.website.com/somefile.pdf";

        $Shipment = new Shipment();
        $Shipment->setBarcodeUrl($barcodeUrl);

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $em->persist($Shipment);
        $em->flush(); 

        // Saving The File:
        $saveto = __DIR__.'/../../../../web/uploads/documents';
        $ch = curl_init($barcodeUrl);
        $fp = fopen($saveto,'wb');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        fclose($fp); 

        return new Response('Created shipment and saved file");
    }

    protected function getUploadRootDir()
    {
        return __DIR__.'/../../../../web'.$this->getUploadDir();
    }

    protected function getUploadDir()
    {
        return 'uploads/documents';
    }
}
```

Every time I run the above code. It saves a file in the web folder, that has the path I have mentioned as it's name. The file does not open, doesn't even save with any extension.

Saved File: `/../../../../web/home/webmuch/uploads` in the web folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really a Symfony2 problem. You need to also pass a filename to fopen.
So should be something like this:

```
$fp = fopen(sprintf('%s/%s.%s', $saveto, sha1($barcodeUrl), 'pdf'),'wb');
```

Also I noticed you have `getUploadRootDir()` method that you're not using, I'm assuming because it didn't work for you - the reason is that you're missing a slash in there

```
protected function getUploadRootDir()
{
    return __DIR__.'/../../../../web/'.$this->getUploadDir();
}
```

Last but not least, you can get web location with `$this->container->getParameter('kernel.root_dir').'/../web'`

so

```
protected function getUploadRootDir()
{
    return $this->container->getParameter('kernel.root_dir').'/../web/'.$this->getUploadDir();
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer, $this->container->get('kernel.root_dir') gives me the error: You have requested a non-existent service "kernel.root_dir".

Comment: sorry, should be $this->container->getParameter('kernel.root_dir')

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thanks a lot. But I had to save it in the app folder because for some reason I cannot get the filesystem to return to the parent folder with "/../". It didn't work with __DIR__ and it didn't work with $this->container->getParameter('kernel.root_dir'). I have no idea why?

Comment: @Aayush I actually also made a typo, try `$this->container->getParameter('kernel.root_dir').'/../web'`

Comment: I know, I saw it later, everything works perfectly now. Thanks a lot for your help. I appreciate it.